# Синтактическая ошибка в R.java, других ошибок не показывает

Tags: android, android-support-library

В сгенерированном файле R.java показывает такую ошибку:

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

В других файлах ошибки нет. Это библиотека, android-support-v7. После ее добавления, в ней же тут же появляется эта ошибка. Где искать причину появления этой ошибки?

Comment: большинство ошибок в этом классе связаны с ошибками в файлах ресурсов. На пример, ошибки в XML, или именовании файлов ресурсов...

Comment: @metalurgus как искать ошибку если он ее не показывает, да и это библиотека, не я писала, а только добавила...

Comment: Смотря какую IDE используете, а вообще сложно найти ошибку в xml ресурса, но ищите она там. Посмотрите может быть в menu.xml она

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R файл автоматически сгенерированный, менять в нем что-либо бесполезно. Порывшись в ресурсах я нашла строку в которой была проблема. Удалила эту строку, библиотека заработала. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

1. Покажите весь код файла R.java.
2. Из сообщения видно, что у вас синтаксическая ошибка: забыли дописать "}" в конце класса.

Comment: @AkiraTakahashi 
R.java - автоматически сгенерированный файл. Там около 2824 строк и кода и комментариев. Даже если я в ручную добавляю скобочку эту, после сборки она пропадает. Я Файл этот и удаляла, и пересобирала проект, ничего не помогло. Проблема в том, что больше никаких ошибок не показывает, только эта.